# Create <tr> in table without ID using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, appendchild

I have a question about dynamical row creating to existing HTML table. I am sorry, if question seems stupid, but I am beginner at JavaScript. Here is HTML table **(I cannot change any HTML code here)**:

I have to add rows with JavaScript, but because I cannot add table id to HTML code, it's impossible to do it by insertRow() function. I have tried with this code, but it doesn't work (not even with getElementsByClassName('some-tab')). The rows are not created. Code:

```js
var something = getElementsByTagName('table');
var tableca = something[0];

for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

  var tr = document.createElement('tr');

  var td1 = document.createElement('td');
  var td2 = document.createElement('td');

  var text1 = document.createTextNode('Text1');
  var text2 = document.createTextNode('Text2');

  td1.appendChild(text1);
  td2.appendChild(text2);
  tr.appendChild(td1);
  tr.appendChild(td2);

  tableca.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(tableca);
```

```html
<table class="some-tab">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="Username">Admin</td>
    <td id="Description">STH STH STH!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone help me, please? Thank you very much! :D

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: @Grundy — There's no need to direct people to a 3rd party site. Stackoverflow has had built in live demos for [over a year](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @Quentin, i know, but jsfiddle can be more usual in some cases, also, for example, plunkr better than standart for angular, and snippets with a few files

Comment: Of course you should use insertRow and insertCell instead. And the last statement "document.body.appendChild(tableca);" is just unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your browser's developer tools.

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementsByTagName is not defined
> ```

`getElementsByTagName` is a method of the `document` object and of DOM element objects. It isn't a global.

Just edit the first line of your code.

```js
var something = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
var tableca = something[0];

for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

  var tr = document.createElement('tr');

  var td1 = document.createElement('td');
  var td2 = document.createElement('td');

  var text1 = document.createTextNode('Text1');
  var text2 = document.createTextNode('Text2');

  td1.appendChild(text1);
  td2.appendChild(text2);
  tr.appendChild(td1);
  tr.appendChild(td2);

  tableca.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(tableca);
```

```html
<table class="some-tab">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="Username">Admin</td>
    <td id="Description">STH STH STH!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you can't use getElementsByTagName or ClassName alone. The whole statement is

```
document.getElementsByTagName('TABLE');
```

And then it works

Comment: <tr> still aren't created to my existing table. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe you should check that your script is executed after your html code. Your `<script>` node must be after the `</table>` node in the HTML code, else it won't find any `table` element to put your `tr` in.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to write above; my jS code is in exernal file :)

Comment: @ZanPokerznik But do you know when the code runs ? Before the page's body loads or after ?

Comment: It works now. Function is loaded when body is full loaded. (<body onload>)

Comment: It's what I would have told you to do ;)